# bash - how to get (current) Julian day number?

Tags: bash, julian-date

How to get today's [Julian day number (JDN)](http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Julian_day_number) equivalent? or any date's, for that matter?

I've looked and looked, but only found some functions that produced "year-dayOfYear", not something like: 2457854.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up porting one myself. Here is a [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions):

```
#!/bin/bash

function GetJulianDay # year, month, day
{
  year=$1
  month=$2
  day=$3

  jd=$((day - 32075 + 1461 * (year + 4800 - (14 - month) / 12) / 4 + 367 * (month - 2 + ((14 - month) / 12) * 12) / 12 - 3 * ((year + 4900 - (14 - month) / 12) / 100) / 4))

  echo $jd
}

function GetTodayJulianDay
{
  year=`date +"%Y"`
  month=`date +"%m"`
  day=`date +"%d"`

  todayJd=$(GetJulianDay $year $month $day)

  echo $todayJd
}

# samples

todayJd=$(GetTodayJulianDay)
echo "got today jd: $todayJd"

yesterdayJd=$(GetJulianDay 2017 4 9)
echo "got yesterday jd: $yesterdayJd"
```

Test it: https://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/JulianDate

Comment: A+ for using the *navy.mil* resource. The *jpl.gov* site is also very good for such things.

Answer (score 6):

in bash `date +%j` returns julian date.

```
[root@TX-Serv-1 ~]# date +%j
108
```

Also Julian dates in the future are pretty easy too.

```
[root@es-host01 ~]# date --date='10 days' +%j
119
[root@es-host01 ~]# date --date='2 weeks' +%j
123
```

Comment: _How_ does "108" resemble anything like a JDN? please read the question thoroughly

Comment: While it's answering the wrong question (ordinal date/day-of-year number instead of Julian date), this is a helpful little command. Here's the difference between the two, which shows why there could be confusion if you only read the question's title: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Terminology

Answer (score 2):

You could get the Unix date with `date +%s --date=YYYYMMDD` and use it to [compute the Julian Day from Unix date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466321/convert-unix-timestamp-to-julian)

It would end up something like:

```
echo $(( $(date +%s --date=YYYYMMDD) / 86400 + 2440587 ))
```

*Edit:* I don’t know how important this is, but some people like to add 0.5 to the conversion. Basically this means that if your current date/time is after noon, the conversion would put the Julian date 1 day later.

Comment: I went with the tried and tested Java version we'd been using. Yours looks much neater. I'll give it a chance when I have some time.

Comment: For my bash function, I used `local epoch_seconds=$(date -j -f %Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S $year-$month-$day-12:00:00 +%s)`, then `local epoch_days=$(( epoch_seconds / (60*60*24) ))`, and finally `local jd=$(( epoch_days + 2440588 ))`.  Depending on need, may have to be mindful of local time versus UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
OLD_JULIAN_VAR=$(date -u -d 1840-12-31 +%s)

TODAY_DATE=`date --date="$odate" +"%Y-%m-%d"`
TODAY_DATE_VAR=`date -u -d "$TODAY_DATE" +"%s"`
export JULIAN_DATE=$((((TODAY_DATE_VAR - OLD_JULIAN_VAR))/86400))
echo $JULIAN_DATE
```

the mathematically

```
[(date in sec)-(1840-12-31 in sec)]/86400
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch Julian Date of any specific day

```
RUN_DT=$(date -d "20230715" "+%Y/%m/%d")
JULIAN_DT=$(date -d $RUN_DT +%Y%j)
echo "$JULIAN_DT"
```

Output: ***2023196***

To fetch Julian date for First day of previous month?

```
RUN_DT=$(date -d "20230715 - 1 month" "+%Y/%m/01")
JULIAN_DT=$(date -d $RUN_DT +%Y%j)
echo "$JULIAN_DT"
```

Output: ***2023152***

To fetch Today's Date Julian date

```
REQUEST_DATE=$(date +%Y%j)
```

Output for 30 Aug 2023: ***2023242***

Comment: It has already been answered.